# Finding explicit form of group homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let there be $f: \mathbb Z_{50} \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{15}$ group homomorphism so that $f(7)=6$.
Find explicit form of $f$.

What's the approach to this type of questions?

Is it possible that the form is $f(m)=(m-1) \mod 15$ for $ \forall \,m \neq 1$?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$\Bbb Z_{50}=\langle\,1\,\rangle=\langle\,7\,\rangle$$

for any $\;a\in\Bbb Z_{50}\;$ there exists $\;k_a\in\{0,1,2,...,49\}\;$ s.t. $\;a=k_a\cdot 7\;$ , so...

Comment: How did you know that 7 generates the group?

Comment: @jeeee, because $\;g.c.d.(7,50)=1\;$, of course. Have you studied something about finite **cyclic** groups?

Comment: But 6 isn't a generator, so isn't that wrong?

Comment: sorry i have no idea how to solve this :[

Comment: No @jeeee, that isn't wrong. The homomorphism can be non-injective (and thus non-surjective, too...why?), as in this case: $$25\cdot 6=0\pmod{50}$$ and thus this homomorphism maps $\;\Bbb Z_{50}\;$ onto $\;\Bbb Z_{25}\;$ ...and its explicit form is $$7k\mapsto 42k=-8k\pmod{50}$$ since we can write, as we saw before, any element in $\;\Bbb Z_{50}\;$ as $\;7k\;,\;\;k\in\{0,1,2,...,49\}\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio notice the problem says $\mathbb Z_{15}$ and not $\mathbb Z_{25}$. Also, shouldn't the mapping be to $42k$ $(mod 15)$?

Comment: Rats, that's true @charlie. I over saw that...but it never matters asteh basics remain: $$ord_{15}(6)=5\;\;\text{since}\;\;6\cdot 5=0\pmod{15}$$ , so the mentioned homomorphism maps $\;\Bbb Z_{50}\;$ into a subgroup of order $\;5\;$ in $\;\Bbb Z_{15}\;$ ...and yes, the mapping then is $\;42k=12k=-3k\pmod{15}\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(1)=k$, then $\phi(7)=7k$. While $7k \mod 15 = 6$, we get k=3. So $\phi(x)=3x$.